# WordPress Mobile Pack Custom Page Template

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, mobile, pack

Hoping someone can help.

I've inherited a WP based website which has WPMP already installed & activated & working on it (I can see it work on many pages).

I've had to create a custom template & a few pages that use this template. Unfortunately, when I switch to mobile mode (or check out the new pages on my iPhone), no posts show.

The custom template has to query for posts multiple times to display different groupings of posts in different places. I have a feeling these dynamic queries are removing the ability for WPMP to see any posts at all.

So the only thing I can think of doing is somehow "providing" WPMP the list of posts to see.

How do I do this?

Please help...

- O8

Answer (score 1):

I think that in your situation you best way will be to:
1. Upgrade wordpress to the lastest version.
2. Install http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wptouch/ - that will do all the work for you on mobile.

Answer (score 1):

if you are having trouble fetch posts in mobile pack, then in custom temple, please run wp_query or SQL command to select all posts and declared a

```
Global $posts
```

and once $posts is populated then the regular commands which are used in the loop can be executed to show posts.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using `wp_reset_query` after each loop?
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_query

Use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) with Firefox, or Chrome's or Safari's or IE8's developer tools to see what's loading on your site and check for javascript errors and css conflicts.